# How to fill Drawer menu dynamically in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to add a Drawer menu to my app. The menu items should be loaded from the sqlite database. I managed to display a list of items that are stored in the database on a Scaffold using `FutureBuilder` but I can't make it work inside a Drawer. Here is what I tried:

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeView({Key key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: DBHelper.dbHelper.getAllCourses(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              List<Course> coursesList = snapshot.data;
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: coursesList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) =>
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.school),
                      title: Text(coursesList.elementAt(index).subject + ' ' + coursesList.elementAt(index).name),
                    ),
                );
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MyApp View Prototypes'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
              child: Text('click on the hamburger menu to open the drawer')
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Everytime I run the app the drawer remains empty.

**EDIT:** It came out that no data was loaded from the database. I fixed this issue and now my code works.

Comment: You can download the courses in the init method and call setstate updating the list of items.

Comment: @Ikazuchi could you be a bit more clear? What is the init method?

Comment: Add an if statement : if(snapshot.hasData) else snapshot.error and log the error. Likely your future builder is returning empty data

Comment: @MohammadAssadArshad it seems that you're right: I get an empty list. Gonna fix my database issues first then.

Comment: I was having a database issue. My code works now. But still: Is it good practice the way I am doing it? Or should I use the ```initState()``` method? (I think that's what @Ikazuchi meant)